# WWW::Mechanize with SSL works but response is slow

Tags: performance, perl, ssl, https, www-mechanize

I'm using [`WWW::Mechanize`](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize) to make an HTTPS connection to a piece of hardware running its own SSLv3-based web server.

My code works but the responses to get(), submit() and click() come back slowly, ranging from 6 to 12 seconds.

There's a configuration issue that's causing the server's IP address to differ from the one it uses in its certificate. For that reason, I'm ignoring hostname verification for the time being.

That could be the reason why WWW::Mechanize is slow. However, there isn't any slowness when using a regular web browser to perform the same functions. I'm running on Solaris 10 (sparc), with Perl 5.20.1 and OpenSSL 0.7.9d. Mechanize runs fast when doing normal HTTP connections to a different server.

I also tried all of the agent aliases. No improvement.

```
use WWW::Mechanize;
$ENV{HTTPS_VERSION}                = 3;    # Try SSLv3 first
$ENV{PERL_LWP_SSL_VERIFY_HOSTNAME} = 0;    # Ignore verification
my $agent = WWW::Mechanize->new( autocheck => 1 );
$agent->get($https_url);
$agent->credentials( $username, $password );
$agent->get($status_url);
print "$agent->{content}\n";
$agent->form_number(2);
$agent->click();
print "$agent->{content}\n";
```

**UPDATE:**

I updated OpenSSL to 1.0.1j and recompiled Net::SSLeay 1.66. I also updated IO::Socket::SSL to 2.002. I still saw the same behavior.

I then recompiled LWP::Protocol::https 6.0.6 and WWW::Mechanize 1.73 for good measure. Same behavior.

I added `use IO::Socket::SSL qw(debug3);` to my script. I can see a 6 second delay in the debug output.

```
Fetching initial page...
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:2537: new ctx 11476520
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:529: socket not yet connected
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:531: socket connected
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:553: ssl handshake not started
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:589: not using SNI because hostname is unknown
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:640: set socket to non-blocking to enforce timeout=180
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:653: Net::SSLeay::connect -> -1
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:663: ssl handshake in progress
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:673: waiting for fd to become ready: SSL wants a read first
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:693: socket ready, retrying connect
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:653: Net::SSLeay::connect -> -1
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:663: ssl handshake in progress
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:673: waiting for fd to become ready: SSL wants a read first
# >>> There's a 6 second delay here <<<
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:693: socket ready, retrying connect
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:653: Net::SSLeay::connect -> -1
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:708: ssl handshake done
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:2570: free ctx 11476520 open=11476520
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:2582: OK free ctx 11476520
Credentials...
Fetching status page...
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:2537: new ctx 11476520
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:529: socket not yet connected
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:531: socket connected
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:553: ssl handshake not started
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:589: not using SNI because hostname is unknown
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:640: set socket to non-blocking to enforce timeout=180
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:653: Net::SSLeay::connect -> -1
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:663: ssl handshake in progress
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:673: waiting for fd to become ready: SSL wants a read first
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:693: socket ready, retrying connect
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:653: Net::SSLeay::connect -> -1
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:663: ssl handshake in progress
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:673: waiting for fd to become ready: SSL wants a read first
# >>> Another 6 second delay <<<
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:693: socket ready, retrying connect
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:653: Net::SSLeay::connect -> -1
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:708: ssl handshake done
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:2570: free ctx 11476520 open=11476520
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:2582: OK free ctx 11476520
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:2537: new ctx 11476520
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:529: socket not yet connected
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:531: socket connected
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:553: ssl handshake not started
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:589: not using SNI because hostname is unknown
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:640: set socket to non-blocking to enforce timeout=180
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:653: Net::SSLeay::connect -> -1
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:663: ssl handshake in progress
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:673: waiting for fd to become ready: SSL wants a read first
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:693: socket ready, retrying connect
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:653: Net::SSLeay::connect -> -1
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:663: ssl handshake in progress
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:673: waiting for fd to become ready: SSL wants a read first
# >>> Another 6 second delay <<<
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:693: socket ready, retrying connect
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:653: Net::SSLeay::connect -> -1
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:708: ssl handshake done
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:2570: free ctx 11476520 open=11476520
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:2582: OK free ctx 11476520
Submitting form...
# Repeat of behavior when fetching the initial page, except ctx is 12700768
```

**SOLUTION:**

Here's my working script with the changes described in my conversation with Steffen. Keep-alive was the solution.

```
use WWW::Mechanize;
use IO::Socket::SSL qw(debug3);                     # Turn on level 3 debug
use LWP::ConnCache;
$ENV{PERL_LWP_SSL_VERIFY_HOSTNAME} = 0;             # Ignore verification
my $agent = WWW::Mechanize->new(autocheck => 1);
$agent->conn_cache(LWP::ConnCache->new);            # Enable keep-alive
$agent->get($https_url);
$agent->credentials($username, $password);
$agent->get($status_url);
$agent->form_number(2);
$agent->click();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> There's a configuration issue that's causing the server's IP address to differ from the one it uses in its certificate. For that reason, I'm ignoring hostname verification for the time being.

Better use the SSL_verifycn_name setting of IO::Socket::SSL to define, which name you expect in the certificate.

> That could be the reason why WWW::Mechanize is slow.

Probably not, because you are just disabling checks. Disabling does not make it slower, but enabling would not make it slower too because these checks are fast and don't need any additional network activity.

> I'm running on Solaris 10 (sparc), with Perl 5.20.1 and OpenSSL 0.7.9d.

I doubt that you are using 0.7.9d, you probably mean 0.9.7d. It is still a very unusual configuration, that is using a modern Perl with a 10 year old version of OpenSSL. I would suggest that you use a current version instead and maybe your problems go away then.

> However, there isn't any slowness when using a regular web browser to perform the same functions.

Current browsers use a modern TLS stack which has more efficient ciphers, session resumption etc. Again, try to use a recent version of OpenSSL instead.

Comment: Thank you for the tip about SSL_verifycn. I'll give it a try. You're right. It is 0.9.7d and it is an unusual configuration. If I upgrade OpenSSL, I think I'll have to update some Perl modules, like Net::SSLeay. I don't have Crypt::SSLeay, which I don't think I'm using with WWW::Mechanize anyway. I'll post my results as soon.

Comment: WWW::Mechanize uses LWP::UserAgent, which since version 6.0 uses IO::Socket::SSL by default. IO::Socket::SSL itself uses Net::SSLeay. Crypt::SSLeay was used in LWP version before 6.0. Since you are explicitly disabled checking of hostname you must use the IO::Socket::SSL backend, because Crypt:SSLeay does not check the hostname anyway. So it should be enough to recompile Net::SSLeay.

Comment: I updated to OpenSSL 1.0.1j and added the results to my orignal post above.

Comment: It looks like it is waiting for the server to complete the handshake. Since `$ENV{HTTPS_VERSION}` is for the old Crypt::SSLeay backend only and has no effect on the IO::Socket::SSL backend please try to set the version with `$agent->ssl_opts(SSL_version => 'SSLv3')` instead. If this does not help I would like to see a packet capture (cloudshark.org) from this slow connection and from a fast browser connection to find out the difference.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm on a private network. I'm comparing captured data right now. I'll see what I can do to make this available. I tried `SSL_version => 'SSLv3'` as you suggested. No change in behavior.

Comment: Problem solved. I enabled keep-alive by adding `use LWP::ConnCache; $agent->conn_cache(LWP::ConnCache->new);` to my script. There's still a 6 second delay for the first get(), but all subsequent fetches are fast. Thank you Steffen for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: You might also compare the ciphers used. IO::Socket::SSL prefers by default ciphers with forward secrecy, but with SSLv3 these are only DHE ciphers. These have a high initial overhead at the server side, especially if the server is an old low end system. Something like DES-CBC3-SHA might be faster in this case.